# How do I make the active menu item highlighted?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a .services section which has a sidebar-menu. How can I make the item I clicked light white and write it into the existing JS code? I tried in the JS code to simply set the addition of css to the color property, but in the end all the items light up

Site http://ct03638.tmweb.ru/

Code jsfiddle.net/p7ubnje6/

```js
 $('.sidebar-menu li ').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var index_ = $(this).closest("li").index()
        $('.sidebar-menu li').removeClass('big');
        $(".sidebar-menu li:eq(" + index_ + ")").addClass('big');
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add style for active link:

```
.sidebar-menu li.big a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your webiste, you have

```
.sidebar-menu li a
```

**which has a gray color (#777)**

you have to change the color of the "`a`" tag, since it's "deeper" in the scheme

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lmwqadp8/4/

```js
$('.sidebar-menu').on('click', 'li', function () {
   $(this).addClass('big').siblings().removeClass('big')
})
```

If I understand your question correctly